# How to clear only those CSS floatings of blocks that are within the clearing element's parent?

Tags: css

If you directly want to go to the fiddle, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/AGVFn/9/

---

I'm currently working on a web design whose structure should look somewhat like this:
[image: The structure of my planned design]

As you can see, the grey blocks (I'll call them "content blocks") will contain some text as well as images (or other blocks) that need to be floated to the right inside their container.

The height of the content blocks should always be large enough for the content block to display the whole text content as well as all images.

The navigation box on the right should also adjust to the size of its content accordingly.

---

HTML-wise I want to have a (mostly) semantic structure - so I started with this:

```
<div class="mainContentContainer">
    <nav>
        <div>
            <h2>Navigation</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#one">Article #1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two">Article #2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Article #x</a></li>
                [...]
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <article id="one">
        <div>
            <img src=".." />
            Lorem ipsum...
            <img src=".." />
            More lorem ipsum...
        </div>
    </article>

    <article id="two">
        <div>
            Lorem ipsum...
            <img src=".." />
            More lorem ipsum...
        </div>
    </article>

    [...]
</div>
```

I then started to create CSS definitions for my design. I added `float: right;` to the navigation bar on the right as well as to the images inside my content blocks.

However, I ran into the following problem: In order for the content blocks to adjust its height to the text AND to the floated images accordingly, I need an (empty) element at each content block with `clear: right;`. (This can of course be done with an `:after` rule.) However, this clearing element will make the first content block expand so far that it is too large (i.e. large enough to possibly also contain the navigation block). This not what I want.

I set up a small demonstration in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AGVFn/9/

---

My question boils down to: **How do I clear only those CSS floatings of blocks that are within the clearing element's parent?**

If this happens to be impossible in CSS: Is there another way to create to create the sketched design with none or only slight changes in the HTML structure? (If the HTML structure has to be changed, the changes should not 'destroy' the semantics!)

---

**EDIT 2014-06-26 12:35 UTC**

[A solution proposed by ajm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24430593/1560865) suggested dropping the clearing `:after` element for content blocks and simply adding `overflow: hidden;` to the content block rule.

This won't work since content blocks might also contain explicit clearing elements. (Example: Sometimes the start of a new paragraph should be aligned with the associated floating element. In such a case the paragraph needs to have `clear: right;`.)

Comment: If you're just floating images, why not just use `align=right` on the images?

Comment: @Malcoda you mean text-align?

Comment: I want to be HTML5-compatible. And `ALIGN` is not part of the HTML5 standard anymore. Also the floated elements might also be other content, not just images.

Comment: No, just `align-right` on the image. But if Hauke P. wants to be HTML5 compatible, then nevermind :).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need visible overflow, `overflow: hidden;` will expand the height of your `article`s without `clear`:

```
article {
    background-color: #9a9a9a;

    margin-bottom: 1.5em;

    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;

    padding: 0.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That snaps the height of your first box to its content.

Comment: Huh!? Wow. I'm stunned - why in the world does this work!? Thanks!

Comment: Ah, but I just realized that this won't work in all cases. A `clear: right` might also appear at other places inside the content blocks. I'll update my question accordingly.

Comment: Good approach.  You can set the value of `overflow` to either: `auto` or `hidden` to get the same effect, that is, triggering a block formatting context.

Comment: You don't need to remove the clearing elements, this approach works fine as is.